# Error al cargar los datos de transacción: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html

La pagina trae registros segun la fecha que selecione en la pagina, la 1era vez tenga datos o no funciona bien pero cuando vuelvo a seleccionar otra fecha ya me devueleve el error:
Error al cargar los datos de transacción: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

esto es lo que imprime en consola:

**

```
23:25:37.597 Elemento seleccionado al principio: 
<tbody>
transaction.js:25:28
23:25:37.763
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/transaction?selectedDate=2023-09-15
[HTTP/1.1 204  1539ms]

23:25:39.308 La lista de transacciones está vacía. transaction.js:54:29
23:25:39.308 Intentando seleccionar el elemento... transaction.js:62:20
23:25:39.309 Elemento seleccionado: 
<tbody>
transaction.js:64:20
23:25:39.310 Contador: 0 transaction.js:65:20
23:25:39.310 Código de estado de la respuesta: 204 transaction.js:68:18
23:25:39.310 Código transactiondataDataList: 
Array []
transaction.js:69:18
23:25:39.311 La respuesta fue un 204, la lista está vacía. transaction.js:101:25
23:25:48.096 2023-09-04 transaction.js:21:17
23:25:48.097 Intentando seleccionar el elemento al principio... transaction.js:23:28
23:25:48.097 Elemento seleccionado al principio: null transaction.js:25:28
23:25:48.101
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/transaction?selectedDate=2023-09-04
[HTTP/1.1 200  703ms]

23:25:48.810 Intentando seleccionar el elemento... transaction.js:62:20
23:25:48.811 Elemento seleccionado: null transaction.js:64:20
23:25:48.811 Contador: 1 transaction.js:65:20
23:25:48.812 Código de estado de la respuesta: 0 transaction.js:68:18
23:25:48.812 Código transactiondataDataList: 
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
transaction.js:69:18
23:25:48.816
Error al cargar los datos de transacción: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    cargarExternalData http://localhost:8080/js/transaction.js:103
    promise callback*cargarExternalData http://localhost:8080/js/transaction.js:61
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/js/transaction.js:27
```

**

Codigo HTML:

```js
let contador= 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#transactiondata').DataTable();

    // Obtén la fecha actual en formato YYYY-MM-DD
    const fechaHoy = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    // Obtén una referencia al elemento de entrada de fecha por su ID
    const fechaSeleccionada = document.getElementById('fechaSeleccionada');

    // Establece la fecha de hoy como el valor predeterminado del campo de entrada
    fechaSeleccionada.value = fechaHoy;

     console.log('Contador antes opencalendar click:', contador);

    $('#openCalendarButton').on('click', function() {
        // Aquí puedes abrir el calendario y permitir al usuario seleccionar una fecha
        // Supongamos que la fecha seleccionada se almacena en una variable llamada "selectedDate"
        const selectedDate = obtenerFechaSeleccionada();
        console.log(selectedDate);
        if (selectedDate) {
                   console.log('Intentando seleccionar el elemento al principio...');
                   const elementoSeleccionado = document.querySelector('#transactiondata tbody');
                   console.log('Elemento seleccionado al principio:', elementoSeleccionado);
            // Si se selecciona una fecha, llama a la función para cargar los datos
            cargarExternalData(selectedDate);
        }
    });
});


function cargarExternalData(selectedDate) {



    // Aquí puedes usar la variable "selectedDate" para hacer la solicitud a la API
    const headers = getHeaders();
    const url = '/transaction?selectedDate=' + selectedDate;
    let status =0;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            // Si la respuesta no es exitosa, manejar el error aquí
            console.error('Error en la respuesta de la API:', response.statusText);
            return Promise.reject('Error en la respuesta de la API');
        }
         if (response.status === 204) {
                    // Si la respuesta es un 204, la lista está vacía
                    console.log('La lista de transacciones está vacía.');
                    status =response.status;
                    return []; // Devolver una lista vacía
                }

        return response.json(); // Devuelve los datos JSON solo si la respuesta es exitosa
    })
    .then(transactiondataDataList => {
           console.log('Intentando seleccionar el elemento...');
           const elementoSeleccionado = document.querySelector('#transactiondata tbody');
           console.log('Elemento seleccionado:', elementoSeleccionado);
           console.log('Contador:', contador);
           contador = contador + 1;

         console.log('Código de estado de la respuesta:', status);
         console.log('Código transactiondataDataList:', transactiondataDataList);
         let listadoHtml = '';
         if (status !== 204) {
             if (!transactiondataDataList || transactiondataDataList.length === 0) {
                    // Si la lista está vacía, puedes realizar alguna acción o mostrar un mensaje
                     let transactionDataHtml ='<tr>' + '<td>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';
                     listadoHtml += transactionDataHtml;
                    console.log('La lista de transacciones está vacía.');
                } else {

            for (let transactiondata of transactiondataDataList) {
                let transactionDataHtml =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.date + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.dateUtc + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.openDateUtc + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.instrumentName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.period + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.profitAndLoss + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.transactionType + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.reference + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.openLevel + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.closeLevel + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.size + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.currency + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + transactiondata.cashTransaction + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                listadoHtml += transactionDataHtml;
            }

                }
            } else {
                console.log('La respuesta fue un 204, la lista está vacía.');
            }
            document.querySelector('#transactiondata tbody').outerHTML = listadoHtml;

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al cargar los datos de transacción:', error);
    });
}



function obtenerFechaSeleccionada() {
    // Obtener el valor del elemento de entrada de fecha
    const fechaSeleccionada = document.getElementById('fechaSeleccionada').value;

    // Asegurarse de que se haya seleccionado una fecha válida
    if (fechaSeleccionada) {
        return fechaSeleccionada;
    } else {
        alert('Por favor, selecciona una fecha válida.');
        return null; // Devuelve null si no se selecciona una fecha
    }
}
function getHeaders() {
    return {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': localStorage.token
    };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>DESDE STATIC</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
            rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this page -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

<!-- Page Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

        <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
        <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
            <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">Users System <sup>2</sup></div>
        </a>


        <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
                <span>IG API RESOLUTION</span></a>
        </li>

        <!-- Divider -->
        <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

        <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
        <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
            <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
        </div>

    </ul>
    <!-- End of Sidebar -->

    <!-- Content Wrapper -->
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div id="content">

            <!-- Topbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>

                <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">



                    <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                    <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" id="txt-email-usuario">...</span>
                            <img class="img-profile rounded-circle"
                                 src="img/undraw_profile.svg">
                        </a>
                        <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                             aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                Profile
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                Settings
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                Activity Log
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                Logout
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </nav>
            <!-- End of Topbar -->

            <!-- Begin Page Content -->
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Gestión de Usuarios</h1>
                <input type="date" id="fechaSeleccionada" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01"  />
                <!-- Botón para obtener la fecha seleccionada -->
                <button id="openCalendarButton">Obtener Fecha Seleccionada</button>

                <!-- DataTales Example -->
                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Listado de Usuarios</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="transactiondata" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Nombre Completo</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <h1 th:text="${mensaje.contenido}"></h1>
                                <!-- Agrega un botón para abrir el calendario -->

                                <p>Datos de la API:</p>

            <!--                    <tr th:each="item : ${externalDataList}">
                                    <td th:text="${item.AccountId}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.balance}"> </td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.balance}"> </td>
                                </tr>
-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Main Content -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
            <div class="container my-auto">
                <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                    <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- End of Footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

<!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
<a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>

<!-- Logout Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level plugins -->
<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level custom scripts -->
<script src="js/transaction.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No veo porque se pierde  document.querySelector('#transactiondata tbody').outerHTML = listadoHtml;
En la segunda llamada al calenderario se pasa la fecha de forma correcta se dirige al controlador y al servicio devolviendo datos pero no se pintan en la pagina